# why plus (++) string in request url not sent to server with asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i have 2 application . coreproject and clientproject.
i send a string text from clinetproject to coreproject. i have only one problem to send plus (+) chacter to coreproject . for example my requset url ecive to coreproject is Request = {Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:whateever/api/v1/Search/Search?Query=++++++&PageNumber=1&PageSize=5', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Host: localhost:...

and but my actionContext.ModelState.IsValid is false
my string text in clinet project is ++++++ but it recive to coreproject and change to " " and model.isvalid is false ? why?

Comment: Because the `+` character needs to be percent-encoded in order to not be interpreted as a space, try searching.

Comment: Thank You CodeCaster . work For me.thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In query part plus sign mean space. If you want sent plus sign you have to encode it with %2b.

So now you RequestUri should look like:

```
http://localhost:whateever/api/v1/Search/Search?Query=%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b&PageNumber=1&PageSize=5',
```

Comment: Thank you.Sousuke .That is work for me.

Comment: No problem, so in that case you can mark this as answear :)